# Why can protocol be omitted from absolute paths on a webpage?

Tags: url

I recently ran across a website that had some interesting styling on a select element.  I went to investigate and found this (names changed to protect the innocent):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.domain.tld/file.js"></script>
```

It works despite `HTTP:` being omitted.  What is the purpose of leaving off the protocol?

Comment: There are a lot of answers, but no actual references to the standard which specifies this behavior.  I think this sounds useful, but I wouldn't want to use it if it's just an implementation quirk.

Comment: @Teddy It is apparently called "Class X7.45" and is specified in RFC 1808 http://www.w3.org/Addressing/rfc1808.txt

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881054/is-a-url-starting-with-valid

Comment: For future readers, it is secs. 2.2 and 2.4.5 of @mwcz's link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will use the protocol you're already using. Useful for sites with both `https` and `http` versions.

So if you're on `https://www.domain.tld/file.js` the script will be `https://www.domain.tld/file.js`.

If you're on `http://www.domain.tld/` the script will be `http://www.domain.tld/file.js`.

Answer (score 3):

i believe this is short hand for a relative path to the protocol.  So it should use the same protocol as is being used for that session. e.g if you grabbed that page with http, then this url is relative to http protocol

Answer (score 1):

The purpose is that the scheme (ie. `http` or `https`) can be determined relative to the containing page. This is useful if you have a common piece of code included in multiple pages that can be served via `http` or `https`.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose is to "use the same protocol as in the current URL" -- presumably (?) useful if the page can be reached both as `http:` and `https:` (I have a hard time thinking of other protocols yet that it might be useful for, and even this one is not a clear-cut use case).