# html - links without http protocol

Tags: html, protocols, hyperlink

Is there a reason we include the `http` / `https` protocol on the `href` attribute of links?

Would it be fine to just leave it off:

```
<a href="example.com">my site</a>
```

Comment: Compare `<a href="example.com">` and `<a href="example.html">` - given that the browser can't guess what a link points to based on extension what should it do? Or `<a href="example.pl">` - is that a link to a [Polish web page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.pl) or a [Perl file](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/pl)?

Comment: The part of the URL that makes a link go externally is the // not the protocol. The protocol only tells the computer what device to use on the link. You can link to "http://example.com", https://example.com, ftp://example.com or just //example.com. The latter stating that you should use your current client's protocol (usually a browser http/https, but could be an email client, etc.) and is extremely useful when you consider a site having both http and https protocols running.

Comment: The question should be sharpened. Only omitting the protocol leads to URLs starting with "//". That is discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018183/why-can-protocol-be-omitted-from-absolute-paths-on-a-webpage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a <script src="http://...">?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The inclusion of the “http:” or “https:” part is partly just a matter of tradition, partly a matter of actually specifying the protocol. If it is defaulted, the protocol of the current page is used; e.g., //www.example.com becomes http://www.example.com or https://www.example.com depending on the URL of the referring page. If a web page is saved on a local disk and then opened from there, it has no protocol (just the file: pseudo-protocol), so URLs like //www.example.com won’t work; so here’s one reason for including the “http:” or “https:” part.

Omitting also the “//” part is a completely different issue altogether, turning the URL to a relative URL that will be interpreted as relative to the current base URL.

The reason why www.example.com works when typed or pasted on a browser’s address line is that relative URLs would not make sense there (there is no base URL to relate to), so browser vendors decided to imply the “http://” prefix there.

Answer (score 3):

URLs in href are not restricted to only HTTP documents. They support all the protocols supported by browsers- ftp, mailto, file etc.

Also, you can preceed URL name with '#', to link to a html id internally in the page. You can give just the name or directory path, without a protocol, which will be taken as a relative URL.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to trick the browser with a redirect service, such as bit.ly and goo.gl (which will be discontinued soon), in addition to others.

When the browser realizes that the url of the shortcuts is https, it automatically releases the link image, the link is released and instead displays the http image, without showing the original link.

The annoying part is that, according to the access, it will display in the panel control of your redirector, thousands of "clicks", which is actually "display".

With this experience I'm going to look for a Wordpress plugin for redirection and create my own "redirects links". So I will have https // mysite.com /id → redirect to http link.