# How to know if a request is http or https in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am using nodejs and expressjs. I wonder if there is something like `request.headers.protocol` in the clientRequest object. I would like to build the baseUrl for the web links. So if the request was done via https I would like to keep https in all links.

```
    var baseUrl = request.headers.protocol + request.headers.host;
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

**Edit:** For Express, it's safer and recommended to use [`req.secure`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.secure) (as @Andy recommends below). While it uses a similar implementation, it will be safe for future use and it also optionally supports the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header.

That being said, for your use case it would be quicker to use Express' [`req.protocol`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.protocol) property, which is either `http` or `https`. Note, however, that for outgoing links, you can just refer to `//example.com/path`, and the browser will use the current protocol. (See also [Can I change all my http:// links to just //?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just))

For node `Request` object without Express:

<del>It's in `req.connection.secure` (boolean).</del>

**Edit:**
The API has changed, for **Node 0.6.15+**:

An HTTPS connection has `req.connection.encrypted` (an object with information about the SSL connection). An HTTP connection doesn't have `req.connection.encrypted`.

Also (from [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_connection)):

> With HTTPS support, use request.connection.verifyPeer() and request.connection.getPeerCertificate() to obtain the client's authentication details.

Comment: Is this still available in the latest node 0.10 and up?

Comment: Hm, can you verify this for later node versions like 0.8 and up, I cannot find anything of the sort in documentation. But it could be that I am reading in the wrong place.

Comment: This still exists in Node v5.x.

Comment: at least [when using express](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#req.secure), one can rely on `req.secure` (as a boolean property) or likewise `'https' == req.protocol`

Comment: I'm running NodeJs v11.5.0 and the request object does not contain a `.connection.encrypted` -- how can I tell now?

Comment: This answer may be outdated. I'm running a nodejs server on aws w/ ssl and encrrypted is undefined

Comment: Try ``req.socket.encrypted``. In the most recent versions of Node.js, the ``.connection`` property was changed to a ``.socket`` property. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/http.html#http_message_socket

Answer (score 56):

`req.secure` is a shorthand for `req.protocol === 'https'` should be what you looking for.

If you run your app behind proxy, enable 'trust proxy' so `req.protocol` reflects the protocol that's been used to communicate between client and proxy.

`app.enable('trust proxy');`

Comment: oh right, confused with `require('url').parse(..).protocol`

Comment: Nice call on mentioning `app.enable('trust proxy');`
Not using this was causing an redirect loop.

Comment: @Ben what does node v5.x have to do with this? Please read documentation for express 4.x (which is the latest by far): https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.protocol

Answer (score 11):

For pure NodeJS (this works locally and deployed, e.g. behind Nginx):

```
function getProtocol (req) {
    var proto = req.connection.encrypted ? 'https' : 'http';
    // only do this if you trust the proxy
    proto = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || proto;
    return proto.split(/\s*,\s*/)[0];
}
```

Comment: Not anymore - 'connection' is deprecated - @deprecated — Since v16.0.0

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to specify the protocol in URL, thus you don't need to bother with this problem.

If you use `<img src="//mysite.comm/images/image.jpg" />` the browser will use HTTP if the page is served in HTTP, and will use HTTPS if the page is served in HTTPS. See [the @Jukka K. Korpela explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951423/html-links-without-http-protocol) in another thread.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, you are right but for this project I need to detect the protocol.

Comment: But this is not true for universal apps, on server you have to specify the protocol

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']
```

Hope this helped,

E

Comment: Note that this will only work if your app is running behind a reverse proxy that sets this header — which is a good idea, but may not be the case especially in e.g. a local dev environment. (Also, keep in mind that if you're *not* behind a proxy a client could spoof the header, so be careful how you trust it.)

Comment: Also this in some cases gives you the ip not the http host!

Comment: I'm using OpenShift, and this is the correct answer for that service (req.secure and req.protocol don't work); just thought I'd mention in case someone else is too.

Answer (score 2):

This is what works for me:

```
getAPIHostAndPort = function(req, appendEndSlash) {
    return (req.connection && req.connection.encrypted ? 'https' : 'http') + '://' + req.headers.host + (appendEndSlash ? '/' : '');
}
```

Comment: `IncommingSocket` (what `req` actually is) no longer supports a `connection` property (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/http.html#messageconnection).

The replacement is `net.socket` and `net.socket` does not have an `encrypted` property either (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/net.html#class-netsocket)

Comment: @RavenHursT Have you found solution? Seems that express library is using deprecated property as well (https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/8368dc178af16b91b576c4c1d135f701a0007e5d/lib/request.js#L307)

Comment: Nope.. sorry. I stopped using `express` a while back and since use `koaJS` when building APIs...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know whether request is http or https then use this in your code:

```
req.headers.referer.split(':')[0];
```

This will return whether req is http or https.

Comment: it only works when users are redirect from the same site, when use visit the site by inputting domain in browser's nav bar directly, it would not work

Answer (score 1):

If you are using request module and for example want to know what protocol does some www use, you can use: **response.request.uri.protocol**

```
request(YOUR_TARGET, function(error, response, body){
    if (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    else {
        console.log(response.request.uri.protocol); // will show HTTP or HTTPS
    }
});
```

If you need user protocol then use **request.headers.referer.split(':')[0];** just like *@Harsh* gave you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the request protocol string: either http or (for TLS requests) https just use

```
 req.protocol
```

Express documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.protocol

Comment: The question refers to native NodeJS, not framework library abstractions.