# node js URL Parsing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to parse the url in node js. Getting null values from this code. It is receiving value for the path. But not for the host or protocol.,

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
http.createServer ( function (req,res){
    var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    var protocol = url.parse(req.url).protocol;
    var host = url.parse(req.url).host;
    console.log("request for " + pathname + " recived.");
    console.log("request for " + protocol + " recived.");
    console.log("request for " + host + " recived.");
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'});
    res.write('Hello Client');
    res.end();
 }).listen(41742);
 console.log('Server Running at port 41742');
 console.log('Process IS :',process.pid);
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of a URL that doesn't work, and also have you console logged req.url?

Comment: The HTTP protocol doesn't communicate the combined URL in one value for Node to parse out. Only the path and optional query-string are given in `req.url` (for a `GET /foo` request, `req.url === "/foo"`). The `Host` is in a request header, at least in HTTP 1.1 and later.

Comment: So how do I print the host and protocol ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The [HTTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) doesn't communicate the combined URL in one value for Node to parse out.

A request to `http://yourdomain.com/home`, for example, arrives as:

```
GET /home HTTP/1.1
Host yourdomain.com
# ... (additional headers)
```

So, the pieces won't all be in the same place.

- The path and query-string you can get from the [`req.url`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/http.html#http_message_url), as you were doing – it'll hold `"/home"` for the above example.

  ```
  var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  ```
- The host you can get from the [`req.headers`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/http.html#http_message_headers), though a value wasn't always required for it.

  ```
  var hostname = req.headers.host || 'your-domain.com';
  ```
- For the protocol, there isn't a standard placement for this value.

  You can use the advice given in "[How to know if a request is http or https in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348906/how-to-know-if-a-request-is-http-or-https-in-node-js)" to determine between `http` and `https`.

  ```
  var protocol = req.connection.encrypted ? 'https' : 'http';
  ```

  Or, though it isn't standard, many clients/browsers will provide it with the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header.

Answer (score 1):

`req.url` only contains the path not the entire url.
Rest are in request headers.

- For Host: `console.log(req.headers["host"]);`
- For Protocol: `console.log(req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"]);`

Answer (score 1):

you can view this source code:
https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/request.js