# In node.js How do I get the protocol of a request object?

Tags: node.js

```
const URL = require('url').URL;
const myURL = new URL('https://example.org/foo');

console.log(myURL.href);     // https://example.org/foo
console.log(myURL.protocol); // https:
console.log(myURL.hostname); // example.org
console.log(myURL.pathname); // /foo
```

But how do I get it for request url that user made to the server???

Comment: can you do req.header

Comment: it shows all the content in header.

Comment: Actually it's request.protocol, what I was looking for. But thanks for your concern I appreciate it.

Comment: Node is developed for http... So requests handled by your node app are anyways going to be http (or https)...

Comment: Check this out please. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10353248/7006062

Comment: Thanks Antonio :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply by doing `request.protocol` like

```
    exports.nameOfFunction = function(request, response){
    var proto = request.protocol;
    console.log(proto);
}
```

Comment: Is this answer still valid ??

Comment: Depending on what you are using. These answers that do not care about giving context are pretty useless, you are right on that. If you are using `express` the protocol prop is available (https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.protocol), if you are on plain node then this won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

A more modern way to solve this issue:

```js
const request = new Request('https://google.com')
const protocol = new URL(request.url).protocol
console.log(protocol) // prints "https:". Mind the colon
```

You have to create an [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) instance, since [`Request#url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/url) returns a string