# How I can get request protocol like http or https in nextjs in getInitialProps?

Tags: javascript, next.js

getInitialProps is the function of nextsj https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props .

```
Page.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
 const req= ctx.req;
}
```

I want to know about protocol by this `req` object.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to know if a request is http or https in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348906/how-to-know-if-a-request-is-http-or-https-in-node-js)?

Comment: nope,  not getting anything in nextjs.

Comment: `req.headers.referer` should contain the absolute address of page that made request thus you can check it against `https` `req.headers.referer.includes("https://")`

Comment: ^ it won't work properly when the request to your page comes from an external website (referer can be a different resource)