# How to correctly redirect a URL which does NOT start with HTTP or HTTPS protocols?

Tags: java, url, redirect

I am overwriting the `HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect()` method. Normally, a redirect url will start with `http` or `https`. But we do encounter some URLs like this:

`//www.google.com`.

This URL works when you assign this url to `window.location` in js. However, it would fail if we try to redirect this URL. Because it will always consider it as a relative path.

Do you know how to correctly redirect a URL like this?

Comment: from my experience you need the 'protocol' part of the address. Browsers are more tolerant if you miss it off (hence why opening in a new window will work ok). You could look at the source of firefox (or similar) and see how they get around the missing protocol problem. Or test for the protocol in the redirect link and open in a new window if it is missing.

Comment: You may refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951423/html-links-without-http-protocol

Answer (score 0):

You could rely on the following.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getScheme()

This will tell you whether it's http/https

Comment: Hi Dev, how can I check the //www.google.com by using this ServletRequest.getScheme() ?

Answer (score 0):

For handling relative URLs (i.e. ones which don't specify schema or host), you need to copy the missing parts from the `ServletRequest` that triggered the processing. The Java class `URL` has a helper method for that:

```
URL requestURL = new URL( request.getRequestURL() );
URL redirectURL = new URL( requestURL, "//www.google.com" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951423/html-links-without-http-protocol), link without protocol would use the current protocol by default.

Thus you may simply use the protocol of current page.