# Href while running localhost not working

Tags: html, css

so im designing a website using **html, php,** all that fun stuff & im trying to make **facebook, twitter, youtube & instagram** links that will open a new tab and take you to the website. but at the moment the URL is going to `localhost/horizonphotography/www.facebook.com` instead of opening the new tab and THEN going to `www.facebook.com`.

heres my **HTML**

```
<div class="social">      
    <a href="www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
    <img border="0" alt="Facebook" src="img/facebook.png" width="50" height="50">
    </a>

    <a href="www.twitter.com" target="_blank">
    <img border="0" alt="twitter" src="img/twitter.png" width="50" height="50">
    </a>

    <a href="www.youtube.com" target="_blank">
    <img border="0" alt="youtube" src="img/youtube.png" width="50" height="50">
    </a>

    <a href="www.instagram.com" target="_blank">
    <img border="0" alt="instagram" src="img/instagram.png" width="50" height="50">
    </a>
</div>
```

and my **css** 'if' required.

```
.social {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 7%;
    width: 300px;
}
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the protocol, or put // at the start of the href attribute. For example:

http://www.youtube.com

Or

//www.youtube.com

Answer (score 6):

Try using a protocol like `http://` or `//` to external links like this :

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
<img border="0" alt="Facebook" src="img/facebook.png" width="50" height="50">
</a>
```

See this good answer on SO : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8951636/6028607

Answer (score 0):

Awesome, needed to identify the protocol as suggested. working well now! thanks everyone!