# Video won't work in safari/chrome using wirewax iframe embed code

Tags: html, iframe

Very new to coding and just learning how to use HTML5 and CSS. I've created a .html document in brackets and set up the boiler plate code. I generated an embed code from wirewax after making a short interactive video. I pasted the code into my document and tested - no sign of the video. I pasted the same embed code into the w3schools text editor and ran it, and it worked. I've no idea why it won't work in my own document and I don't have the frame of reference built up yet to really research or ask the right question! I would love some pointers on what to look for or if I have to put a URL into a style sheet or something like that.

This is the embed code:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 0; padding-bottom: 56.25%;"><iframe style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" width="100%" height="100%" src="//embed.wirewax.com/8066745/?loop=true&noShare=true" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Please note, i havent learned about iframes or video tags yet but want to finish a practice webpage for my employer.

Thanks so much in advance.

Sue

Comment: Please edit your post and paste your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've said I can see that you are not running any local server.

The link in the iframe is

```
//embed.wirewax.com/8066745/?loop=true&noShare=true
```

If you open a html file directly the link in the address bar will be

```
file:///{{Your_path_to_file}}/test.html
```

So the browser will look for ***file:///embed.wirewax.com/8066745/?loop=true&noShare=true*** rather than ***http://embed.wirewax.com/8066745/?loop=true&noShare=true*** and it can't load the page.

Change the link in the iframe from

```
src="//embed.wirewax.com/8066745/?loop=true&noShare=true"
```

***to***

```
src="http://embed.wirewax.com/8066745/?loop=true&noShare=true"
```

and it should work.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951423/html-links-without-http-protocol) why the browser is taking you to ***file:///*** and not ***http:///*** nor ***https:///***

Comment: Pradeep - I tested and this worked. AND I learned something! Fantastic - I really appreciate it and you got me out of a bind.

Comment: @SuePrendo Glad I helped you out. Please mark it as the answer if this worked.