# uploading a URL link Issue in textbox ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, url, syntax, href

This is probably a very simple solution of code syntax of Sql or maybe. 
I have a Text Box. id=textbox1 
I insert a URL in there. eg: www.google.com 
my code in SQL

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Link(URL) values (@URL)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@URL", textbox1.Text);
```

Now on the client side, I have this code to go to the URL

```
 <a href="<%# Eval("URL") %>" target="_blank">Click here</a>
```

My problem is , when I click on the link, instead of going directly to *www.google.com* 
the links adds in the url of the original domain too. 
eg: *www.mydomainname.com/www.google.com*

any assistance please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your're missing the protocol for the URL. I imagine it would work if you enter `http://www.google.com`.

By design href-targets are not limited to the *http* protocol, but can also contain other things like *mailto*, *file*, ...

See [html - links without http protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951423/html-links-without-http-protocol) for some more information.