# jQuery volume UI different than what I pushed out?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I recently finished the UI for a volume slider and then published the code to my website. However, the slider design that shows up on the website is different than the one I had designed.

**Why is this and how can I fix this?**

Original:

[image]

Final (shown on website):

[image]

---

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

---

```js
$(function() {
  // var audioElement = $("<audio>");

  function setVolume(myVolume) {
    if (audioElement != undefined) {
      audioElement.volume = myVolume;
    }
  }

  $("#volume").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    value: 1,
    step: 0.01,
    range: "min",
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      setVolume(ui.value);
    }
  });
});

$("#player").hover(
  function() {
    $('.ui-slider-range-min').css("background-color", "#483EF1")
    $('.ui-slider-handle').css("display", "block")
  },
  function() {
    $('.ui-slider-range-min').css("background-color", "#B3B3B3")
    $('.ui-slider-handle').css("display", "none")
  }
);
```

```css
/* audioUtilities */

.audioUtilitiesDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  /* background-color: darkblue; */
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
}

#player {
  width: 140px;
  height: 30px;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* margin: 0 auto; */
  bottom: 40px;
  /* background: black; */
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px;
}


/* #player:hover {
  background: #483EF1;
} */

i {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -6px;
  color: #666;
}

i.fa-volume-down {
  margin-left: -8px;
}

i.fa-volume-up {
  margin-right: -8px;
  right: 0;
}

#volume {
  position: absolute;
  left: 24px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #505050;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.ui-slider-range-min {
  height: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #B3B3B3;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
}


/* .ui-slider-range-min:hover {
  background: #483EF1;
} */

.ui-slider-handle {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  display: none;
}


/* Volume slider */
```

```html
<div class="audioUtilitiesDiv">
  <div id="player">
    <i class="fa fa-volume-down"></i>
    <div id="volume"></div>
    <!-- <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:**

It seems like jquery ui file is not found I get this error in the console:

> file://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

(Do I have to do something in the terminal maybe? Install it?)

Comment: That looks like a CSS issue. Have a close look at the order of the CSS file you load. Last rule is the one applied (in most cases).

Comment: So I removed the JavaScript and jQuery tags from your question. Nothing to do with it.

Comment: inspect the elements and see what rules are being used - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a problem in on your development environment. I think your computer can't get the jquery-ui css *(with `href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"`)*.

In example below I comment this css link and the slider appeared like your original.

To solve your issue, I think you have to change the href link to `https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css`. And then add flag `!important` next to all css property of `.ui-slider-handle` class to overcharge the basic css of jquery-ui.

```js
$(function() {
  var audioElement = $("<audio>");

  function setVolume(myVolume) {
    if (audioElement != undefined) {
      audioElement.volume = myVolume;
    }
  }

  $("#volume").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    value: 1,
    step: 0.01,
    range: "min",
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      setVolume(ui.value);
    }
  });
  
  $("#player").hover(
  function() {
    $('.ui-slider-range-min').css("background-color", "#483EF1")
    $('.ui-slider-handle').css("display", "block")
  },
  function() {
    $('.ui-slider-range-min').css("background-color", "#B3B3B3")
    $('.ui-slider-handle').css("display", "none")
  }
);
});
```

```css
/* audioUtilities */

.audioUtilitiesDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: darkblue;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
}

#player {
  width: 140px;
  height: 30px;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* margin: 0 auto; */
  bottom: 40px;
  /* background: black; */
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px;
}


/* #player:hover {
  background: #483EF1;
} */

i {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -6px;
  color: #666;
}

i.fa-volume-down {
  margin-left: -8px;
}

i.fa-volume-up {
  margin-right: -8px;
  right: 0;
}

#volume {
  position: absolute;
  left: 24px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #505050;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.ui-slider-range-min {
  height: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #B3B3B3;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
}


/* .ui-slider-range-min:hover {
  background: #483EF1;
} */

.ui-slider-handle {
  width: 16px ;
  height: 16px ;
  border-radius: 20px ;
  background: #FFF ;
  position: absolute ;
  margin-left: -8px ;
  margin-top: -6px ;
  cursor: pointer ;
  outline: none ;
  display: none ;
}


/* Volume slider */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- COMMENT THIS LINE -->
<!--<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>-->

<div class="audioUtilitiesDiv">
  <div id="player">
    <i class="fa fa-volume-down"></i>
    <div id="volume"></div>
    <!-- <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues.

**The first issue:**

*file://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND*

Explanation:

If the protocol is defaulted, the protocol of the current page is used. So, You are starting Your development page directly from the file system, without using a local web-server or a development web server, and the reference to `//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css` is defaulted to `file:` . The other files are downloaded from Your local internet connection, because You provided the full link.

Here is a great answer on SO: [html - links without http protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8951636/4845566)

**The second issue:**

*the slider design that shows up on the website is different than the one I had designed*

Explanation:

From Your remote web site the default protocol will be of course `https` and the reference to the jquery-ui theme CSS will be correctly resolved and the styles are therefore applied to Your `slider` widget.

Now, to customize the base theme, there are two possibilities:

- If Your custom style isn't already specified in the jquery-ui base theme CSS, You need to define it in some way and this will be correctly applied with nothing else to do
- If Your custom style is already defined in the jquery-ui base theme
  CSS, You need to *override* it by using **specificity**. You can
  either use `!important` (see here:
  [What does !important mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-mean-in-css))
  or use a deeper role. Here is a reference: [CSS
  Specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp)

Here is an example how to customize Your `slider` by including the jquery base theme and overriding the needed styles:

```
#volume .ui-slider-handle {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  top: -6px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  display: none;
}

#volume.ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
  border: none;
}
```

*How do You check if Your custom style is already defined inside the jquery-ui base theme?*

The object inspector of the developer tools in Your browser is Your friend here.

---

Example: the gray border around the slider is defined inside the jquery-ui CSS at line 1298 as follows:

```
.ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
}
```

Now, You know that You need to override that style.

Full example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Mh8yFxz7TthnkIKz370F?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

instead of this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: I tried this and although the error went away, the UI on the non-production web went from the original to the ugly final...