# "Need help fixing navigation bar links - Clicking 'Privacy' redirects to incorrect URL"

Tags: html, web, https

This is the current code for my navigation bar:

```
    <nav>
        <a href="example.com"> Fact Generator</a>
        <a href="example.com/privacy">Privacy</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
```

This is my website: `https://example.com/`

When I go to my website and click privacy, it takes me to `https://example.com/example.com/privacy` Any help so it instead takes me to `https://example.com/privacy`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML link not going to external site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70966483/html-link-not-going-to-external-site)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [html - links without http protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951423/html-links-without-http-protocol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an **absolute path** or specify a **root-relative path** for the "Privacy" link.

Here's the corrected code:

```
    <nav>
    <a href="https://example.com">Fact Generator</a>
    <a href="https://example.com/privacy">Privacy</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
```

Or, if you want to use a root-relative path:

```
<nav>
<a href="/">Fact Generator</a>
<a href="/privacy">Privacy</a>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

This way, when you click on the "Privacy" link, it will take you to the correct URL: `https://example.com/privacy`.