# Access the Facebook //connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js with C#

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I am working on pulling news and events to display in my Universal Windows Platform Application (UWP) using C# and have the Facebook SDK installed. The company uses the script below to access the information and display it on their log in website.

```
!function(b,e,f,g,a,c,d){b.fbq||(a=b.fbq=function(){a.callMethod?a.callMethod.apply(a,arguments):a.queue.push(arguments)},b._fbq||(b._fbq=a),a.push=a,a.loaded=!0,a.version="2.0",a.queue=[],c=e.createElement(f),c.async=!0,c.src=g,d=e.getElementsByTagName(f)[0],d.parentNode.insertBefore(c,d))}(window,document,"script","//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js");fbq("init","1446863745630648");fbq("track","PageView");
```

As you can see from the script they are using //connect.facebook.net/en_us/fbevents.js file to store the events. Is there a way I can access and read this file?

Comment: which file? this? https://connect.facebook.net/en_us/fbevents.js

Comment: yes... fbevents.js

Comment: did you click my link above?? starting a url with // means that a page in http will prepend http, and a page in https will prepend https to it.. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881054/is-a-url-starting-with-valid

Comment: hmm. ok well the file is not what I was looking for but your response did answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

did you click my link above?? starting a url with // means that a page in http will prepend http, and a page in https will prepend https to it.. See stackoverflow.com/questions/11881054/… – mentat 3 hours ago